# HighSpeed Sync in Slave Mode

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, high-speed-sync

I have a couple of `SB-910` flashes and they can easily do high speed sync to like 1/8000 sec.
I also have some `PocketWizard Plus III` radio triggers but that model does not support highspeed sync. So if I want to add more flashes to also be able to use them in HighSpeedSync mode, I should either continue buying expensive `SB-910` flashes or pay extra and buy `PocketWizard` triggers that support `TTL` and thus `HighSpeedSync` But how about `Slave mode`? The flashes I like are the famous `LumoPro LP180` flashes, so if I put them in Slave mode can they keep up with highspeed sync of my `SB-910s`? well at at least to let's say 1/2500 sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The flashes I like are the famous LumoPro LP180 flashes, so if I put them in Slave mode can they keep up with highspeed sync of my SB-910s?

AFAIK the LP180 doesn't have any form of high speed sync, so **no.**

Comment: so it depends on the brand of the flash? Meaning are there other flashes that I can find which can catch up to high-speed-sync of my TTL flashes but are just non-Nikon manual flashes? or basically nothing no other manual flash in Slave mode can do this?

Comment: There are SB-910 knock offs like the [MK910](http://www.meikestore.com/product/meike-mk-910-mk910-i-ttl-flash-speedlight-1-8000s-hss-high-sync-speed-master-for-nikon/2267.html) that'll do HSS, but the *manual* part of *manual flash* pretty much means "you set the flash power and trigger it, and it flashes." In other words, nothing fancy. HSS is sort of the epitome of fancy. I suppose it's possible that a manual flash could be triggered repeatedly by the multiple flashes of a master unit doing HSS, but the timing for HSS is critical -- I'd be surprised if it works.

Comment: Also, there are multiple sources on the net that say that one shortcoming of the LP180 is lack of high speed sync. So it's pretty clear that it doesn't just work, at least with that unit.

Comment: Thanks for info and introducing the MK910, this sounds like a great deal. Ordering one! It is really 1/5 of a sb-910 and half price of LumoPro and equal to getting one PocketWizard trigger! wow!